# File can not open when URL contains is % Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimage, nsurl

File can not open when URL contains is % like following example.

File name: **work12%Complete.jpg**

URL: http://.../work12%Complete.jpg

I have try following option for this, But using this option set %25 instead of % , So file can not open in UIimage.

```
var strUrl:String! = documentDetails.value(forKey: "thumbURL") as! String
strUrl = strUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed);
print(strUrl!);
imgView.setImageWith(URL(string: strUrl)!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named : "DefaultImage"));
```

Output: http://.../work12%25Complete.jpg

if pass value directly in url like follow then app crash when UIimage set this url.

```
imgView.setImageWith(URL(string: "http://.../work12%Complete.jpg")!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named : "DefaultImage"));
```

Note:- If i have removed % from file name then created url like http://.../work12Complete.jpg, it's working fine, But i want to solution for file name contains is %.

Comment: is there any possibility that your file name can contain % sign?

Comment: yes rmaddy, i have found file name and url contain % sign from webservice, and i want to handle this.

Comment: Since a file name or url can contain % sign and replacing with this % sign with + (plus sign) can work, then add a one line of code where you can replace any % sign available in a url with + sign. OR just ignore % with empty.  Like below -
                
                yourURL.replacingOccurrences(of: "%", with: "")

Comment: @SalehSultan, I have try with rename on file replace + from % it's working fine, but in server hundred or thousand of file which is contain is %, or it may by put again new file which contain %, So i want to solution for % .

Comment: if i put your solution "replace any % sign available in a url with + sign. OR just ignore % with empty." so file can not found from server. for example "http://.../work12%Complete.jpg" file exist in server but "http://.../work12+Complete.jpg" file can not found from server.

Comment: Confusing. you just said replacing with % sign with + works fine for you. But again said in your last comment 'http://../work12+Complete.jpg" file can not found from server'. Can you please elaborate more clearly, what exactly is your question?

Comment: try two scenario: 1) try with rename 1 file from server replace % to + No any change from my side (ios code) just display image from url, so that one file display properly, But in this case i can not change rename each and every file. 2) if no any change from server side keep file name as it is with % and only change from my side(ios code) replace % to + then this kind of file not found from server, because of in server, file name contains % and i try to display with + so it is not possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141436/discussion-between-saleh-sultan-and-atulparmar).